# Matching a pattern in Java when a few starting characters and a few ending characters are known

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find a pattern which is a string. I know the first few characters of that string. And I also know the set of characters or words the string is ending with. How do I find this pattern? My string is constituted of words and special characters.

My string starts with a special character and ends with a special character followed by any two characters, which are variables.

Comment: Do you mean `start + "(.*?)" + end + special1 + special2`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah. And i know what is the end charcater. But special1 and special2 are unknown . These may vary.

Comment: so you already have your answer with that comment, right? ;-)

Comment: @MohammeSaquib you need to know them when you create the regex at runtime or do you want to find out what they are from the input?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the special character are and want to find them out from the input you can do

```
String regex = start + "(.*?)" + end + "(.)(.)"
```

As @olivier-grégoire points out, this assumes `start` and `end` are sufficiently quoted e.g. use `Pattern.quote(String)` if you are not sure.

The two characters matched will be in group 2 and 3 when you use a `Matcher`

Comment: You should wrap `start` and `end` with `Pattern.quote(String)`.